# openjdk code compilation/ IDE setup

Tags: jvm, java

I am trying to understand openjdk vm code specifically gc code base. i tried to open in CLion but it shows lot of errors. Is there a document which explains how to setup and navigate code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OpenJDK source distribution includes NetBeans project [nbproject](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/file/c23b7c1c24bf/common/nb_native/nbproject) - just open this project in [NetBeans IDE with C/C++ development pack](https://cnd.netbeans.org/docs/hotspot-projects/Using.html). The project already contains configurations for Solaris, Linux, and MacOS. Here is step-by-step instructions(I didn't check them):

- http://marcelinorc.com/2016/02/17/using-netbeans-to-hack-openjdk9-in-ubuntu/
- https://dzone.com/articles/hack-openjdk-netbeans-ide

In case of CLion you can use [the following instructions](https://github.com/JetBrains/jdk8u_jdk).

If you are interested in hotspot project - you can use this CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(hotspot)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 98)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -D_GNU_SOURCE \
    -D_REENTRANT \
    -DLINUX -DINCLUDE_SUFFIX_OS=_linux -DVM_LITTLE_ENDIAN \
    -DTARGET_COMPILER_gcc \
    -DAMD64 -DHOTSPOT_LIB_ARCH='amd64' -DINCLUDE_SUFFIX_CPU=_x86 -D_LP64 -DTARGET_ARCH_x86 \
    -DCOMPILER1 -DCOMPILER2")

include_directories(
    src/share/vm
    src/os/linux/vm
    src/cpu/x86/vm
    src/os_cpu/linux_x86/vm
    src/share/vm/precompiled)

set(SOURCE_FILES
 // CLion will generate includes here automatically on project initialization
)

add_executable(hotspot ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Comment: Hi, could you be a bit more clear about the Clion steps? Because the link seems just to be a project..